# Get a list of lists, iterating a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists like this,

```
big_list = [[1,3,5], [1,2,5], [9,3,5]]

sec_list = [1,3,5]
```

I want to iterate through the `big_list` and check each list values against the `sec_list`. While I check, I want to store the values that are not matching into a another list of lists. So, I did this:

```
sma_list = []
for each in big_list:
    for i,j in zip(each, sec_list):
        if i!=j:
            sma_list.append(i)
```

I get the result like this:

```
[2, 9]
```

However, I need a list of lists like this,

```
[[2], [9]]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer,

```
sma_list.append([i])
```

Enclosing a value in square brackets makes it the first element of a one element list.

This will only work correctly if you have one missing element per list. You're much better off using a comprehension for the whole thing:

```
sma_list = [[i for i, j in zip(each, sec_list) if i != j] for each in big_list]
```

Comment: Nice, What does that `[]` do when I append? putting it to a list?

Comment: List comprehension way is nice. However, if I do inn traditional way like I have, how can I modify that to check for many elements? I have been googling "list of lists" in python, hard to find something that compares a list :(